# Adding functionality to implementation classes without changing the implemented Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have got an interface that defines some service methods for data retrieval:

```
public interface DataReceiver {
    public Data getData();
}
```

Then i have a class that implements this interface and loads the data through a connection. I supply this connection using constructor injection:

```
public class ConnectionDataReceiver implements DataReceiver {
    private Connection connection;

    public ConnectionDataReceiver(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return connection.query("blabla");
    }
}
```

This works pretty nicely. I can instantiate my `ConnectionDataReceiver` objects using the constructor, or i could add a factory method/class that extends the usability by providing an option to select a config file for connection setup. I then use my new class through my interface, so i can easily swap out the implementation (like loading the data from a file instead of a connection).

But what if i want to change my connection during runtime, without instantiating a new `ConnectionDataReceiver`? I would have to add getters and setters for my class. But since they are not part of my public service definition, i can't put them in my interface. I could use the implementation object in my code to set a new connection, but it feels pretty awkward hanging onto a reference to the original object only for maybe changing the connection object:

```
ConnectionDataReceiver conDataRec = new ConnectionDataReceiver(myConnection);
DataReceiver dataRec = conDataRec;
// use dataRec

conDataRec.setConnection(myNewConnection);
// use dataRec again
```

In this example it would be the easiest way to just instantiate a new `ConnectionDataReceiver` and just reassign `dataRec`, but what if the instantiation of my object is really expensive? How do i give my implementation classes additional functionality while still being able to use my old service interface? Or is it generally frowned upon changing data at runtime, when the interface doesn't define that functionality?

Comment: I think you need move the solution of the problem to another layer, layer which use implementation of `DataReceiver` interface.  There you can "inject" another implementation in run-time. You didn't show how `DataReceiver` used, so it is difficult to be more detailed

Comment: I would use the DataReceiver somewhere in my Business Logic Code (Something like 1. Fetch data 2. Process 3. Store in DB). The way i get my DataReceiver doesn't matter as much, DI, Service Locator, you name it, as long as i can easily switch out my implementation in the business logic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that adding following two simple methods in your interface:

`public void setProperty(String name, Object value);`

`public Object getProperty(String name);`

Now with the help of these two simple methods, you may configure as many additional functionalities as you want in your implementation classes without adding a new method for a new feature (of your implementation class) in your `super` type.

This pattern is used in following interface:

`com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsQueueConnectionFactory`

The interface has `setCharProperty`, `setDoubleProperty`, `setFloatProperty` etc so that when they release a new implementation they do not have to modify the interface.

Comment: From question: _How do i give my implementation classes additional functionality while still being able to use my old service interface_

Comment: If your `Service Interface` has a `setProperty(String name, Object value)` method, you can call it in your implementation class multiple times with different `name`-`value` pair and put them in a `java.util.Map`.

Comment: My point was, that OP have already interface, which he don't want to change

Comment: The question does not have any such phrase. Let OP clarify. His concern was `How do i give my implementation classes additional functionality while still being able to use my old service interface?`.  I have answered to this question. From the question it is not clear that OP is using the `old service interface` from a library which he can not change.

Comment: I really don't like object casting and resolving strings to a concrete type, but this solution is rather clean and easily extendable.

Answer (score 1):

My version:

Interface

```
public interface DataReceiver 
{
    public Data getData();
}
```

Implementation

```
public class ConnectionDataReceiver implements DataReceiver 
{
    private Connection connection;

    public ConnectionDataReceiver(Connection connection) 
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Data getData() 
    {
        return connection.query("blabla");
    }
}
```

Interface using in business layer, here method `setReceiver` will assign new implementation of interface in run-time.

```
public class SomeBusinessLogic
{
    private DataReceiver receiver;

    public SomeBusinessLogic(DataReceiver receiver) 
    {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(DataReceiver receiver) 
    {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }
}
```

With this approach you can change implementation of `DataReceiver` in run-time

Comment: This is how i am doing it right now. And in 99% of the cases this is probably the way to go, since instantiating new implementation objects of DataReceiver is fast enough. I was just wondering how to solve the problem, if instatiation isn't fast, but switching out a component of the implementation object itself is fast. Basically i want to keep my old code using the DataReceiver interface, but make specific calls to the implementation object. I was hoping there was a strategy to do that. Like extending interfaces or something like that.

Comment: Purpose of interfaces that your business logic doesn't care about how interface is implemented. But in your case your business logic need to decide which implementation will be used. Raw solution, but maybe business object will have a property of type which contain all types of "receivers".

Comment: Maybe i need to rephrase: Getting my implementations into my business code is easy. I want to know, how i should handle implementation specific calls, or if that is something i just shouldn't do.

Comment: You misunderstand a purpose of interface. Interface "wrap" all specific implementation under one general  "schema". But you want explicitly call specific methods from business logic.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a good way to do that. I would probably go with the approach in your answer, or try extending the interface and working with that (You would have the additional functionality and could still inject it where necessary, as it's a derived interface from the base one).